# How to remove header from this metro ui html template?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the header div from this html template
https://techgyo.com/free-metro-ui-html-template-by-techgyo

But when I put the header div within comments, the icons below the header don't show up anymore why ?!!!

```
    <!--header-->
<!-- <div style="width:100%; height:80px; overflow:hidden; margin: 0 auto; background-color:#333">

  <div style="width:750px; height:80px; margin: 0 auto; overflow:hidden; position:relative">

        <div id="caption" style="height:44px; margin-top:20px;float:left; margin-left:12px; position:absolute">{{params.header.title}}</div>

        <div id="backbutton" style="height:44px; width:44px; margin-top:15px; float:left; position:absolute"> <img src="imgs/backbtn.png" width="44" height="44" /> </div>

       <div id="pagecaption" style="height:44px; margin-top:20px;float:left; margin-left:12px; position:absolute"> Caption </div>
  </div>

</div> -->
```

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific, as we can't see no header, no icons, no relevant html or css

Comment: that header position used for the all page caption and back button. What actually you  want to achive?

Comment: It's not clear what icons you are referring. In the screenshots on the page link you provided there are no icons below the header. Please add screenshots of your situation with and without the header and add more of the code surrounding the header.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the problem that you are facing is that when you comment the header part there is id with name "caption"

```
<div id="caption" style="height:44px;
margin-top:20px;float:left; margin-left:12px; position:absolute"> Company Title </div>
```

so in your script code which is shown below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  TweenLite.to($("#caption"),2,{css:{top:0},delay:1, ease:Power2.easeOut});
});
```

is using that id  i.e #caption on div. Just copy this id="caption" and place in the following div as shown

```
<div id="caption" style="width:750px; height:450px; overflow:hidden; margin: 0 auto; position:relative; margin-top:35px;">
```

Then your animation will work.